# "must run on" or "must be run on"

Tags: grammar

Which one(s) is correct?

> The computer program must **be** run on the operating system XYZ.

or

> The computer program must run on the operating system XYZ.

I thought the second one is correct as well, but a colleague said, only the first one is correct.

---

The original sentence was actually

> Kubeflow must run on Kubernetes.

which I translated to the above, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: They mean slightly different things "must be run" is an instruction for the person doing the running, while "must run" is about the program itself. If it's a legal/administrative rather than technical limitation (you're not allowed to run it on another system or you'll get told off), "must be run" is correct.

Comment: In the context of scheduled TV showings, the metaphoric use of _run_ (no physical running is involved) can be either active (_That show runs at 10pm_) or causative (_They run the show at 10pm_). The difference is whether some person or entity is the subject of _run_; if it is, then the passive can be used to get rid of the agent subject (_The program is run at 10pm_).

Comment: I've seen both, many times.

Comment: @StuartF: Here, it is technical: Kubeflow is not able to run anywhere but on Kubernetes. For technical reasons, I need Kubernetes if I want to run Kubeflow. So... is "must run on" correct in that case?

Comment: Comments are supposed to be for clarification. Answers should go in the answer section.

Comment: @BillOnne
 It is common to give skeletons or short forms of what could be answers in comments.

Comment: I would say that the distinction @Stuart F J makes in a comment is too fine, and would not be reliably understood. To me, in a computer context, the two sentences are nearly interchangeable.